# JavaScipt based equivalent to Excel Pivot or Power BI matrix visualization

Tags: library, javascript, json, table

Is there a JavaScript library that can take JSON data and render it to look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Is there something about "Excel Pivot" or "Power BI" that the solution needs to do which is not shown in the example screenshot?

Comment: @unor, not really. The screen shot doesn't capture the expand/collapse I guess. And the screen shot doesn't show more than 2 levels. Best I could do from a mobile. It is surprising how many js pivot type things that I found simply won't do this.

Answer (score 1):

Syncfusion provides a PivotGrid control [ejPivotGrid](https://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/bootstrap/pivotgrid/relational).
Documentation for binding JSON [link](https://help.syncfusion.com/js/pivotgrid/relational-getting-started)

[image: Syncfusion Chart like Google Analytics]

The entire product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense?refer=srecs39882) program if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.